# "Ignoring command with incorrect key" message in console from jetty

Tags: java, eclipse, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

After starting the jetty-server on my localhost and leaving it idle for about half hour I repeatedly get the message "Ignoring command with incorrect key". I haven't even accessed the site in browser once after starting the server on port 8080.

Stacktrace:

```
[artifact:mvn] 2015-07-09 13:47:55.330:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:!RequestLog
[artifact:mvn] 2015-07-09 13:47:55.383:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Started Jetty Server
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
....// Repeated of same for 
....// 30 more line
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
[artifact:mvn] Ignoring command with incorrect key
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>spring.io.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Spring Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url> 

  <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.1</aspectj.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
        <jetty.version>9.3.0.M1</jetty.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
           <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR 303 with Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JETTY DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
          <version>${jetty.version}</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
          <version>${jetty.version}</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
          <version>${jetty.version}</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To run jetty:run ant tasks -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
           <artifactId>jetty-ant</artifactId>
           <version>${jetty.version}</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Transaction Management -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactions</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
           <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>atomikos-util</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-property-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>spring</finalName>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
                    <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <!-- <goals>
                            <goal>resolve</goal>
                        </goals> -->
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Have to use version 1.2 since version 1.3 does not appear to work with ITDs -->
                <version>1.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see MNG-2972) -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.12.v20130726</version>
                <configuration>
                    <stopKey>todostop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse 
                m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

</project>
```

I know that these messages are coming from using jetty and its generated from the [ShutdownMoitor](https://eclipse.googlesource.com/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project/+/91f6170c40a88c26dd0af863c9f1540c3078a1a6/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ShutdownMonitor.java)/[Monitor](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-start/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/start/Monitor.java?id=43c9bba86d076cae33f4fa21a3effd127c03ae67#n96) class `run()` method and this if loop gets executed,

```
if (!_key.equals(key))
{
    System.err.println("Ignoring command with incorrect key");
    continue;
}
```

What are those commands and why are they ignored? What could be the issue with the jetty server and any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have conflicting Jetty versions in your environment.

Your `<properties>` and `<dependencies>` sections use `<jetty.version>9.3.0.M1</jetty.version>`

But your `<plugin>` section uses version `<version>8.1.12.v20130726</version>`

*Note: [9.3.0 final was released](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00080.html). use version `9.3.0.v20150612` instead. (It requires Java 1.8 btw)*

Comment: Thanks. What is the latest version that will be supported with Java 1.7?

Comment: Don't understand the question, Jetty 9.3 is the latest mature/stable release, Java 1.7 is EOL (End of Life) by Oracle back in April 2015.  All releases of Jetty from here on out are minimum Java 1.8.

Comment: I asking, what is the stable release of Jetty(previous versions) that I can successfully use and is supported with Java 1.7. Right now I am using Java 1.7 in my project. But as per your recommendation I'll soon switch to 1.8 later.

Answer (score 2):

In my configuration, I was using  `<stopPort>9999</stopPort>` and getting this error. Then I changed stop port as `<stopPort>9966</stopPort>` in configuration section and this error was removed.